# Какая разница между dictionary.get(elem) и dictionary[elem]?

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари

Есть ли какая-то разница между:

```
dict_ = {'a':0, 'b':2, 'c':1}
print(dict_.get('a'))
```

и

```
dict_ = {'a':0, 'b':2, 'c':1}
print(dict_['a'])
```

Comment: В документации же написано даже

Comment: @Nobody Пусть Stackoverflow будет лучше любой документации. ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Метод [get](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) для отсутствующего ключа вернет `None` (и позволит указывать значение по умолчанию, что вернется если ключа не будет), а `[]` выбросит исключение `KeyError`:

```
dict_ = {'a':0, 'b':2, 'c':1}
print(dict_.get('d'))
print(dict_.get('d', 999))
# None
# 999

dict_ = {'a':0, 'b':2, 'c':1}
print(dict_['d'])
# KeyError: 'd'
```

Answer (score 4):

Разница состоит в том, что при вызове `dict[key]` для не существующего ключа будет получено исключение:

```
>>> dict = {'a':1, 'b':2}
>>> dict['c']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'c'
```

То же самое действие, но с `dict.get(key)` выдаст `None`:

```
>>> dict = {'a':1, 'b':2}
>>> dict.get('c') is None
True
```

Comment: Каким образом метод словаря get "открывает возможность проверки на существование ключа в словаре"?

Comment: if dict.get('c') is None:
    print("Ключа нету")

Comment: Наверное я не правильно выразился. Сейчас поправлю

Comment: А если в словаре изначально были ключи со значением None?

Comment: Да, я об этом не подумал. Просто никогда не записывал в элементы значение None. Как по мне пустая трата памяти. Исправил)